# numerical computation of an expression

Tags: plotting

I'm a beginner. I would like to draw the plot of a certain function $f(n)$, n=1,2,...

Specifically, my function is

$$\int_0^\infty\left(\frac12 + \frac12\cdot\mathrm{erf}(x/\sqrt 2)\right)^n \exp(-x^2) \mathrm{d}x $$

Thanks!

Comment: Generally, you have a bigger chance of getting an answer if you show some effort of your own, e.g. some code that you got (but doesn't work), or some things you looked at

Comment: Please see [asking guidelines](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). One of which is to be familiar with basic syntax.

Comment: You need `DiscretePlot`, `NIntegrate`, [how to define a function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DefiningFunctions.html) (in terms of `n`), and [avoiding premature evaluation with NIntegrate](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12502)

Answer (score 2):

You need [`DiscretePlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscretePlot.html), [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate.html), [how to define a function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DefiningFunctions.html) (in terms of `n`), and [avoiding premature evaluation with NIntegrate](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12502).

```
f[n_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[(1/2 + 1/2 Erf[x/Sqrt[x]])^n Exp[-x^2], {x, 0, Infinity}]

DiscretePlot[f[n], {n, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]